# Dockable audio player for Windows

Tags: windows, audio

I am looking for an audio player that allows to dock it's playlist to the edge of the screen, so i could access it on mouse-over. I know that AIMP and JetAudio have this feature, and Winamp + cPro combo also allows that, but there are some things i don't like about them:

1. AIMP's docking is rather weird. Zero settings for mouse-over aside, when taskbar is set to auto-hide and some maximized window is in focus, AIMP will not appear on mouse-over. "Always on top" has zero effect. [Devs said](http://www.aimp.ru/forum/index.php?topic=55494.0) (in Russian) it is a desired behavior because, apparently, auto-hiding taskbar + maximized window means that window is fullscreen and AIMP will get in the way, and their suggested solution was to disable auto-hiding of taskbar. Doesn't seem like it's open up for discussion either.
2. JetAudio also doesn't unhide with maximized windows (although the 2-pixel strip is always visible) and just blatantly overlaps auto-hiding taskbar with "Always on top" enabled.
3. Winamp + cPro worked the best of all three. It unhides on hover with any non-fullscreen window in focus and does not prevent me from accessing Start button. However it still blocks upper left corner (i have Firefox menu button placed just in the corner) while still hidden, it's obsolete and prone to crashes (can't even exit properly when docked) and i generally don't like it's sound.

I've also been thinking about Xion, with it's skinning capabilities, but i believe it doesn't have mouse-over triggers and i'm unsure about it's further development.

Comment: Perhaps you could consider having a hotkey to bring it to the front, as an alternative to exapnd on hover?

Comment: @Mawg Well, i guess it is an option, but i'm a more of a mouse person (another possibility is to hide/unhide player on click, which Xion is perfectly capable of) and hover would be preferable.